# Access request Attributes (Set in managed bean before redirect) in Filter by precreating FacesContext

Tags: jsf

I am setting the request attribute in managed bean before redirect the request through faces-config as follows:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("foo","bar");

return "redirect_success";
```

After this i m trying to access this request attribute in my filter through pre creating FacesContext

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("foo");
```

Finally not able to get this attribute in filter itself but i am able to get the same attribute again in second managed bean very easily.
Is there any way to get it in filter itself?

Comment: One more thing I am not using JSF2 so i can't use navigation case to pass parameter/attribute

Comment: Whats the scope of this bean i.e. Request or Session?

Comment: request,I don't want to use session scope

Comment: I think thats the problem. You will loose updated data as soon as you come out of the scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Store in session and let filter remove it from session if necessary.

   ```
   externalContext.getSessionMap().put("foo", "bar");
   ```

   There's by the way no need to create `FacesContext` yourself in a `Filter`. Just cast `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest`.

   ```
   HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
   String foo = (String) session.getAttribute("foo");
   session.removeAttribute("foo");
   ```
2. Use `ExternalContext#redirect()` to add it as request parameter.

   ```
   externalContext.redirect("other.jsf?foo=bar");
   ```

   And then in `Filter`:

   ```
   String foo = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getParameter("foo");
   ```

Comment: Thanks Balus i am taking the first one